# How to intercept the http request if I am using AWS Amplify in React

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, apollo-client

For my current web application, I am not using Axios to send request but using AWS, logRocket, apolloClient and etc. Is there a way to intercept those http request to handle the error response? If not, what do you recommend me to do?